# Find limit of the function $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2x)}$

Tags: limits

Find limit of the function:  $f(x) = \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2x)}$

Solve:

$\lim\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2x)} =\lim\frac{(\ln(x))'}{(\ln((2x))'}=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{\frac{1}{2x}} = 2 $

However, the answer is $1$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You have not specified $\lim_{x\to ?}$. I suppose it's $\infty$?!

Comment: Note that $\ln(2x) = \ln(x) + \ln(2)$ therefore $\ln(2x) = \ln(x) + C$ where $C=\ln(2)$. The functions $\ln(2x)$ and $\ln(x)$ have the same derivative, because they defer by a constant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The derivative of $\ln(2x)$ is not $\frac{1}{2x}$ but $\frac{1}{x}.$

You might also explain what limit is in question. However, the answer will remain the same.

Comment: All too easy.  +1 - Mark

Answer (score 4):

Also, another way
$$
\frac{\ln x}{\ln (2x)}=  \frac{\ln x}{\ln x + \ln 2}=\frac{1}{1+\ln(2)/\ln(x)}
$$
which tends to $1$ as $x\to\infty$, or as $x\to0$.

Answer (score 2):

You got the derivative of $\ln x$ wrong. Use the chain rule $u(v)' = v'u'(v)$:

$${d\over dx}\ln(2x) = 2\cdot{1 \over2x} = {1\over x}$$